# How can I compare rates of evolution for two sets of proteins?

Tags: evolution, bioinformatics

I have a list of candidate proteins as the result of my analysis. I am now trying to find various characteristics that they have in common. One of the things I would like to check is if my candidates are evolving faster or slower than the rest of the proteins in my dataset.

Now, I know how to do this manually by building multi species alignments for each of my proteins and calculating ka/ks ratios for each set of alignments. This, however, is not a trivial process and I really do not want to do this manually for my ~1500 candidates.

Can anyone suggest a tool that will take two lists of proteins and return an estimate of evolutionary rate for each one?

I am primarily interested in human but also mouse, yeast, fly and worm. Ideally, I would need a tool that can take a list of proteins, assign them to an orthologous group and return a value representing the rate of evolution for that group.

Comment: I think you'll have to build the MSA regardless of the strategy that you use. You could try faster tree-based methods.

Comment: are you working on species that have already been sequenced (for which you might info in databases), or do you have novel sequencing data?

Comment: @MichaelKuhn definately sequenced. I am working on human primarily. There should be a database around that can give me this information right?

Comment: The [eggNOG database](http://eggnog.embl.de/) also contains alignments for protein families, but these are on the amino acid level. So you would still somehow have to go back to a nucleotide alignment, which I'm not quite sure how to do. :-/ Might be a good question to ask on BioStar with its larger bioinf audience.

Comment: @MichaelKuhn, protein data is fine, I just realized my original question was not clear enough and have updated it. I said genes in the original because I thought it would be easier to find a relevant tool. My bad.

Comment: @terdon: if you want to compute ka/ks ratios, you need to look at the nucleotide sequences, no?

Comment: @MichaelKuhn, yup, that's why I had said genes in my original question. Since you suggested a protein database, i wanted to make it clear that protein data is fine. It does not necessarily need to be ka/ks, any metric of evolutionary change will do. There could, for example, be a database out here that has calculated homology scores for protein families, that would be fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

If protein alignments are sufficient for you, I suggest that you look at the [eggNOG database](http://eggnog.embl.de). There you can download mappings from proteins to protein families, and for the families you can also download pre-computed multiple (protein) sequence alignments.

I guess depending on the type of analysis you want to do you would have to trim the alignments to get only homologous regions (for example, see this [recent paper<sup>[1]</sup>](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0030288)).

---

1. [**Wu M, Chatterji S, Eisen JA**. 2012. Accounting For Alignment Uncertainty in Phylogenomics. PLoS ONE 7(1): e30288, doi:10.1371/journal.pone.0030288.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0030288)